# How to create a publicly visible, provably random seed ahead of time? (Verifiable random number)

Tags: random, random-seed

Imagine that you are hosting a debate with *n* participants and you wish to split them in half in a completely random fashion.

One might do so by creating a list of participants, randomly shuffling that list, then forcing the first *n/2* participants to debate as a team.

If this debate was particularly important, however, we would want to ensure that the teams we have created are *provably* random in a way that is publicly visible. We want to be able to show that the teams we have created are not the direct result of any human's decisions. Would there be a way to do this?

I believe this problem boils down to the issue of creating a seed for a random number generator that is based on the state of the world at a particular time, but I'm not sure. Is this a problem software engineers have tackled before, and is there an API out there for this?

Comment: Please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I thought the debate example would be sufficient. Can you explain what about it is not clear? This idea can have many applications in software engineering, and I need it for one of my projects, which is why I'm posting it here.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? What languages? Sources? This is more of a very broad question that is difficult to narrow down, might help to flesh out the question more with concrete code examples to assist.

Comment: I haven't been able to research this problem because it's incredibly difficult to google / search about. You just get results for online RNG's and CS1-level questions about how to create random numbers in particular languages. The best solution I can come up with off the top of my head is to use the closing price for a particular stock on a specific day to seed a RNG. This question doesn't have anything to do with particular languages and/or code snippets. It's more about how to accomplish a particular problem regarding random numbers that can arise in software engineering and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be thinking of is [*verifiable random numbers*](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Verifiable_Random_Numbers), which are random numbers generated using data that will be disclosed along with all the information needed to verify them. The most prolific use of verifiable random numbers in practice I am aware of is found in the selection procedure for the Internet Engineering Task Force's Nominations Committee (or NomCom for short). RFC 3797 describes this selection procedure, as well as how verifiable random selection works in general.

Another related technology is the *verifiable delay function*, which is a function that takes noticeable time to compute (for example, to hash publicly disclosed data to a random-looking number) but for which it's easy to verify whether the output is correct. This is described in two works, among others:

- Lenstra, A.K., Wesolowski, B. "A random zoo: sloth, unicorn, and trx", 2015 (before the concept was coined).
- Boneh, D., Bonneau, J., et al. "Verifiable Delay Functions", 2018.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know the term existed, and it feels great to have a word to associate with the concept. The RFC 3797 link is a great read... thanks!